# dhcpd.conf rule-based mapping

Tags: mac-address, mapping, dhcp-server

We have ~100 physical nodes which can host a large number of VMs apiece.  We need to set up dhcpd on one machine to distribute addresses in a predictable fashion based on MAC address.

We'd like to go with a scheme such as:

```
Physical host address: A.B.255.X
VM address range: A.B.X.Y
VM MAC range: 54:52:00:00:x:y
```

where

```
x = Hex(X)
y = Hex(Y)
```

I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/79748/assign-dhcp-ips-for-specific-mac-prefixes) which would let us set up A.B.X.* pools based on MAC prefix 54:52:00:00:x:*, but this has two drawbacks:

1. Each pool is dynamic, so no direct y<->Y mapping
2. We'd have to explicitly name all the pools in the dhcpd.conf (~100 of them)

Is there some way to succinctly specify a scheme like this in dhcpd.conf?